# PHP and EXE files

Tags: php, ftp, exe, execute, passthru

When I searched for a way to execute a PHP script within another PHP script, I found the function *passthru()* at http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.passthru.php. I scrolled down and saw something with the registry, command line and EXE files. **Is it possible to run a EXE file from a PHP script (with *passthru()*, *exec()* or something else) on a server.**

If it is possible, is there a way to get the result or output of the EXE file?

And if all works, is there a way to use .NET applications?

Thank you in advance :)

I'm sorry, if my English isn't very good.

Comment: Have a look at [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec).  It returns the program output as a string.

Comment: Use an exe .Net app from PHP, via shell_exec...the problem is how do you get the otuput from the app...what kind of output that .net app produces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual passthru() does whats on the label, it passes trough stdout. If there is a browser on the other side it gets directly send to that.

If you want the results you could try backticks, this works because PHP is loosely based on Perl. :)

So, for example:

```
$foo = `mybinaryprogramm someparameters $somemoreparametersrightfromavariable`;
#now go and do something usefull with $foo
```

I should mention that you should sanitize $somemoreparametersrightfromavariable somehow, but i hope that you see that as good practice. :)

Comment: That kind of spelling for shell or exec is new to me. This is very cool.